# Facebook Sharing button - og:url, og:title shows redirect page url and title and not original path

Tags: php, facebook, url, redirect

Facebook debugger shows:

Fetched URL : `_http://site/SSTMP1019`

Canonical URL: `_http://site/site/login`

**Redirect path**

original : `http://site/SSTMP1019`

302 : `http://site/login`

og:url: `http://site/login`

But my meta tags in my site showing orginal canonical url`http://site/SSTMP1019`, title but fb debugger shows different canonical url and og:url. I dont know why it happens.

But my original page `http://site/SSTMP1019` redirects to login page may be bcoz of that it shows login url i think.

if it so, how to clear this issue.